# How to get the View with Layout to read .js files from Scripts folder?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, layout

I am working on this `ASP.NET MVC` project where I am trying to add a `Layout` to my `View`. I have some `.js` files in my `Scripts` folder in the project, which I want to load in my `View` so that the components, such as `DatePicker`, `Validation` can work. However, by adding the `Layout` to the `View`, I see that I am getting the following error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

I understand this as, `jQuery` is not available for the `View`. But, I have the `jQuery` file in the Scripts folder. When I remove the `Layout` and add references to the `scripts` in the `View` directly, in `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>` way, I am not getting the error, and the `View` is performing correctly with the necessary functionalities.

Code snippets:

**Create.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="~/Controller/Create" id="myForm">
        ...
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(select)" })
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form').validate({
            ...
        });
    });
</script>
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application Name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>

                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>

        </footer>
    </div>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", false)
</body>
</html>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

**Scripts folder:**

[image: Scripts folder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the RenderSection("Scripts" below the Jquery and Bootstrap one

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
 @RenderSection("Scripts", false)
```

also add the javascript in de view inside the Scripts rendersection

```
@section Scripts { 

<script>..</script>
}
```

Comment: On doing that, I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setDefaults' of undefined`

Comment: That line is present in `<script></script>` in my `View`.

Comment: That means that $.validator is undefined. Did you include the js file for validation?

Comment: I would be helpful if you update your question with the changes you made based o my suggestions

Answer (score 0):

in your `_Layout.cshtml` inside `<body>` include jQuery `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Application Name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>

            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>

    </footer>
</div>
```